# htaccess to change only URL address

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site and need htaccess code to make this change in the address bar without making any physical changes in the server folders

example.com/data/65767.html
to be
example.com/65767

example.com/data/56-45.html
to be
example.com/56-45

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horribly inefficient, you need to make sure your links get changed to point to the one without `.html`, but...

```
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect so that the browser shows the non-.html URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /data/([0-9-]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite the non-.html URI back to the .html URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9-]+)$ /data/$1.html [L]
```

This works with `/data/<any number of digits or "-">` URIs. If you want it to work with anything, replace the `[0-9-]` with `.`

---

EDIT:

> can we also redirect `example.com/65767.html` to be `example.com/65767` and the content from `example.com/data/65767.html`

Yeah, just change the first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /(data/)?([0-9-]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine , But i need to add something else if possible 

can we also redirect example.com/65767.html
to be
example.com/65767

and the content from example.com/data/65767.html